# Using SVD for clustering

Tags: clustering

The dataset that I am experimenting with is in the form of a table with columns userid and itemid. If there is a row for a given user and a given item, that means the user accessed the item (like in an online store). I am trying to cluster similar items based on this data. If a pair of items is accessed together often, then the items are similar.

Because this is a case of a high dimensionality (# of users and items will be in 10,000's) I think I am justified in trying to use SVD as a pre-clustering step and then do some classical clustering. When I tried doing this I got poor clustering results when compared with simple hierarchical clustering. Items that weren't very similar were being bucketed together in one dimension, while there were available dimensions that weren't used. The results weren't completely random, but they were definitely worse than the output from the hierarchical clustering. I attempted the SVD step with Mahaut and Octave and the results were similar. For the hierarchical clustering I used the Jaccard measure.

At this point I am starting to doubt the notion of SVD as a way to reduce dimensionality. Do you think that SVD cannot be used effectively in this case (and why?) or do you think that I made some mistake along the way?

Comment: Do you use every userid and every itemid as a separate dimension?

Comment: When comparing items the number of dimensions is the number of users. Think of items as vectors of 1's and 0's where each dimension corresponds to some user and the value is 1 if the user accessed the item and 0 otherwise.

Comment: The real question here is: does standard PCA work well with binary variables? And I'd say that the answer is "no". Binary variables are not continuous (you can't get .73 in your user-item matrix), but instead categorical (only 0s and 1s are allowed, "yes"-s and "no"-s and nothing in between). IIRC, [MCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis) is a standard analogue of PCA for categorical data. Though, my personal approach would be to use [RBMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine), which can also handle non-linearities.

Comment: It is possible that there are algorithms more suited to categorical data than SVD. However, SVD is often cited as the tool for dimensional reduction in the context of latent semantic analysis. See the response by buruzaemon, for example. In that case the SVD is applied to the term incidence matrix which is also made of 1's and 0's. Also some form of matrix factorization (may be SVD with some regularization) was successfully used in the Netflix competition to predict user ratings for movies (the ratings are integers 1-5). Therefore, I don't think it is easy to write SVD off in discrete case.

Comment: Re using RBMs: Aren't RBMs for classification (supervised learning)? I am interested in clustering (unsupervised learning). Anyway RBM's are probably off limits for me because RBMs are not implemented in Mahout and I cannot use anything licensed by GPL for legal reasons.

Comment: 1. In LSA, SVD is not used for dimension reduction, but instead for finding semantic concepts. If you want dimension reduction, use PCA (or MCA). 2. For continuous variables it makes sense to talk about real values (e.g. .73) and order of values, for categorical - no. For Netflix it makes sense to say "user likes X as much as 4.5" and "mark 4.5 is higher than 3.88". For values "man" and "woman" (even represented as 1 and 0) there's nothing between them (e.g. what would mean value .73?) and no specific order ("man" > "woman" or vice versa?). Decide for yourself which case is yours.

Comment: 3. RBM may be used for data compression/dimension reduction, see relevant sections of my [earlier answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114385/what-is-the-difference-between-convolutional-neural-networks-restricted-boltzma/117188#117188)

Comment: If every item is assigned some semantic concepts, then that can be used for clustering. I believe that my case is analogous to the latent semantic analysis and the netflix data set because in all examples in the absence of data the default value in the matrix is zero. For netlix: zero doesn't mean that the user gave that movie a zero rating, it means that he didn't give any rating. Therefore netflix rating is also a categorical value. In fact I would experiment with the netflix dataset the same way by mapping all ratings to 1 and mapping absence of a rating to zero.

Comment: Re RBMs: This is interesting. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: In Netflix 0 is just an encoding for NA (not available) values. It's not a continuous or categorical variable, it's just missing datum, and should be treated separately. E.g. you want your model to predict values from 1 to 5, but not zero - it would be nonsense (how even would you interpret it? predicting that user haven't given a rating?). So your case is _somewhat_ similar to LSA, but definitely not Netflix dataset.

Comment: I agree it isn't very appropriate to mix NAs with ratings. However, the data set is sparse--no user rates all movies. If we want to apply SVD to the dataset and exclude NA values, we would be applying it to an empty set or we will be narrowing the dataset down extremely to a subset of users and a subset of movies, so that each movie is rated by each user. So NAs have to be assigned some values to perform SVD at all. In this paper (http://research.cs.queensu.ca/TechReports/Reports/2006-527.pdf) the authors treated NAs as no-opinion with score 3 (see page 11). Sounds like it worked for them.

Comment: Often people use mean of all ratings for specific film. E.g. if movie got ratings (2, 4, 2) from 3 users, all other user ratings (which are NAs in the dataset) are assigned (2+4+2)/3 = 2.66.

Comment: If a user bothered to rate the item, then that means that the user is somewhat interested in this item. I assume that users don't access items at random, but do so according to their personal tastes. Missing data is interpreted as negative feedback. Why would it be more appropriate to give mean rating for all users? The mean would be an estimator only conditionally that the users provide some rating, because this characterizes the sample space. It seems that the mean is appropriate for different purposes than mine, like modeling the rating function with the assumption that a rating is given.

Comment: It's up to your assumptions. There are ways to assess performance of both models, so you can always check what assumption was closer to the truth.

Answer (score 2):

We are using Singular Value Decomposition in the much same manner as you, except rather than clustering similar items, we are using a reduced-rank matrix to power a recommendation engine based on a term-document matrix in Latent Semantic Indexing.

From your brief description, your approach seems sound enough. However, I highly recommend reading [Berry, Dumais & O'Brien's Using Linear Algebra for Intelligent Information Retrieval](http://lsirwww.epfl.ch/courses/dis/2003ws/papers/ut-cs-94-270.pdf).

Key to using SVD is selecting an acceptable rank-k approximation to the original sparse matrix. You should carry out some exploratory analysis to see how much variance can be explained, using the singular values in the diagonal matrix Sigma. This question was brought up in [this question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49646/for-a-random-matrix-shouldnt-a-svd-explain-nothing-at-all-what-am-i-doing-wro).

A lot of the papers I've read suggest anywhere a rank k from 200 to 300 singular values. In a proof-of-concept implementation, we had original sparse matrix of about 10000 rows (unique terms) to about 1000 columns (unique documents), and we were capturing just under 85% of the variance with only 300 singular values.

However, that really hinges upon the nature of your data, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have tried varying the rank for the approximation. I tried ranks 40, 100, 300, 1000. I expect that with the rank 40 it would classify items into 40 available dimensions. If that classification into 40 classes is good, I would have no issue with that. However, it seems that some dimensions were simply not being used. A lot of dissimilar items ended up in the same dimension.